# Reason for code working in Sandbox but not in Production

Tags: apex

I have a small piece of IF logic that updates the field on object record. This code was working fine is my sandbox so I moved it to production but I realized this logic is not working in production. Any ideas what could have gone wrong or Am I missing something. Any suggestions would help me. Thanks!

```
 for(Sales_Territory_Mapping__c salesRepMapping : salesRepMappings){
            //system.debug('TEST SalesTerrMName__c '+ salesRepMapping.SalesTerrMName__c);
            if(salesRepMapping.Role__c=='FSALM'){
                a.Sales_Rep_M_Name__c = salesRepMapping.Sales_Rep__c;
                a.AccTerritoryNameM__c = salesRepMapping.SalesTerrMapName__c;
            }
```

I am displaying this field in other class

```
  Ship.AccTerritoryNameM__c = accountWithUpdatedReps.AccTerritoryNameM__c;
```

The above logic should be updating the field AccTerritoryNameCS__c with SalesTerrMapName__c field from an object called Sales_Territory_Mapping__c.

Comment: It would help if you provided all or some of your code with an explanation of what it should do.

Comment: Do the same values tested in your sandbox also exist in your production org?

Comment: I did. It worked in Sandbox.

Comment: How did it deploy if logic was not working. How did the tests pass? You also need to define not working. It's going to be tough for us to debug other than saying the values do not match requirements

Comment: I have updated the code and tried to explain.  I haven't posted the whole code because it's too long and this is the only piece that's not working. I do not have a lot of deployment experience so I wanted to know can these things happen and of yes what could be the reasons.

Comment: @SFDCLearner Assuming there isn't an exception, the two basic possible reasons your if statement doesn't execute are that `salesRepMappings` is empty, or none of the `Sales_Territory_Mapping__c` objects in it have a `Role__c == 'FSALM'`.  It's also possible that `Sales_Rep__c` and `SalesTerrMapName__c` are null in the record.

Comment: The most likely reason is permissions. Make sure that the fields in question are visible to the profiles of the users involved.